# Split a file based on the string from the other file

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk, split

I have two files and i want to divide file1 into number of parts which are equals to number of lines in file2.

Here each line from file2 will be compared to file1 and all the matched records from file1 are formed as new file.

file1

```
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974096" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"/> 
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974099" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SHOW TABLES"/> 
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974095" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"/> 
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974094" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"/> 
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974099" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"/> 
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="21974094" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="SET NAMES utf8"/>
```

file2

```
21974096
21974100
21974095
21974094
21974099
```

required output:

```
21974094.txt

==========================================
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17"
SQLTEXT="SET NAMES utf8"

==========================================
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17"
SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"


21974099.txt

==========================================
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17"
SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"

==========================================
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17"
SQLTEXT="SHOW TABLES"


21974095.txt

==========================================
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:31:17"
SQLTEXT="SHOW COLLATION"

...
```

To achieve this with awk i have written a code like below but it is not satisfying my requirement.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4];next}!($4 in a){ print $2 "\n" $6 "\n=========\n" > $4 ".txt"}' file2  file1
```

Can any one please help me how to achieve the above requirement with awk or any other shell command.
(It has to generate minimum of 10000 files and it should complete generating files in max 10 minutes.)

## 1st TRY

If i have executed below command, it is almost reached but not completely satisfying the requirement.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{split($4,b,"\"")}(b[2] in a){print $2"\n"$10"\n=========\n" > b[2]".txt"}' file2 file1
```

**OUTPUT from one of the file**

```
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="/*
=========

TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="/*
=========

TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="SHOW
```

But i want OUTPUT like below

```
TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="/*show variables"
=========

TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="/* select * from table "
=========

TIMESTAMP="2013-08-26T19:57:34"
SQLTEXT="SHOW collations "
```

Means here i need to specify delimiter for only file1 as '"' and no delimiters for file2..

Can any one help regarding this ?

Comment: Can you use GNU's version of awk?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a number in file2 doesn't exist in file1?

Comment: the number always exist......Because the numbers taken from file1 by doing some filter.

Comment: Are you running this process once, or do you have to run it on a regular basis?

Comment: it is something to be kept in cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the split function to separate the fourth word by the `"` character, so that you get the number that matches the values in file2. You should also `a[$1]` in the firth block.

This script should work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{split($4,b,"\"")}(b[2] in a){print $2"\n"$6"\n=========\n" > b[2]".txt"}' file2  file1
```

UPDATE:

As long as there are not extra quotes in file1, we can use the `"` character as a field separator:

```
awk -F\" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($6 in a){print "TIMESTAMP=\""$2"\"\nSQLTEXT=\""$10"\"\n=========\n" > $6".txt"}' file2  file1
```

We split the input file with the `"` character as a delimiter, so field $2 is the timestamp, field $6 is the conn. id, and filed $10 is the SQLTEXT.

The first block `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}` populates the array with the coonection ids from file2 ( NR == FNR for the first file). With `($6 in a)` we filter the lines of the second file (since we called next in the first block), for which the connection id is an index of table `a`. If we find a match, then the block `{print "TIMESTAMP=\""$2"\"\nSQLTEXT=\""$10"\"\n=========\n" > $6".txt"}'` is executed, which prints the relevant information to the file conn_id.txt

Comment: You shouldn't see any output. But four files `21974094.txt
21974095.txt
21974096.txt
21974099.txt` should be created, with the test files from the examples.

Comment: Yep, there they are. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution... but it is incomplete please refer question which i have edited just now.....

Comment: No...I think it is just because the specified delimiter is used for both files here... we have to use this as delimiter for only file1 because file2 doesn't have '"' inside it......Any help ?

Comment: @vidyadhar What output do you get now? It seems to work over here

Comment: Thank you very much.... it's working...just a small mistake from my side...Will you please add explanation to the above...Please ...

Comment: @vidyadhar Added a small explenation

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use `awk` but it works:

```
while read -r n
do
    echo "Generating $n.txt"
    grep $n file1 | sed 's/^.*\(TIMESTAMP="[^"]\+"\).*\(SQLTEXT="[^"]\+"\).*$/=======================\n\1\n\2\n/' > $n.txt

    # If you don't want an empty file when there's no match, add this line
    if [ ! -s $n.txt ]; then rm -f $n.txt ; fi
done < file2
```

Comment: grep and sed both are costly and here they are in loop...Oh my!.. Every time it has to read the file and do the entire file scan.... Here speed is very important as i have already mentioned in my question..So can you help me solve this without shell scripting loops...

Comment: @vidyadhar I would agree that these are costly compared to other solutions. Your original problem statement indicated you had a lot of files to do, but you said, "with awk or any other shell command". You indicated "less than 10 minutes" but file sizes aren't indicated and it's possible this shell method could do it in under 10 minutes depending upon file sizes. For best performance, I'd recommend writing in a scripting language such as Python, etc. What languages are you familiar with?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the file size is around 500 MB.... and i am basically not a programmer...but i am little familiar with java and c,c++,perl...but here i have achieve this with shell scripting or with shell commands like sed,awk,etc....

Comment: That script will fail cryptically for various contents of the input file and/or the directory you run it from, etc., etc. awk was invented to parse text files - just use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that `awk` is the superior solution for this problem. That solution has already been accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This one's my solution for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    f = ARGV[2]
    while (getline id < f) {
        ids[id] = 0
    }
    ARGV[2] = ""
}

match($0, /.*<AUDIT_RECORD.* (TIMESTAMP="[^"]*").* CONNECTION_ID="([^"]*)".* (SQLTEXT="[^"]*").*/, a) {
    id = a[2]
    if (id in ids) {
        key = id "|" ids[id]++
        timestamps[key] = a[1]
        sqltexts[key] = a[3]
    }
}

END {
    for (id in ids) {
        count = ids[id]
        if (count) {
            file = id ".txt"
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                key = id "|" i
                printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", "==========================================", timestamps[key], sqltexts[key] > file
            }
            close(file)
        }
    }
}
```

Run it with

`gawk -f script.awk file1 file2`

I actually prefer to preprocess the second file before entering the loop for the first file since I don't like adding unecessary condition checking.

You can also just modify `printf` if it's not the exact output you wanted.

Among other solutions actually, gawk's match could allow one to be specific on which parameters should really be targeted so the above code could also work if other lines would have slightly different format like other extra key/value pairs around.

**UPDATE**

This one's simpler but risks opening too many output files at once depending on the number of entries.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    f = ARGV[2]
    while (getline id < f) {
        ids[id] = 0
    }
    ARGV[2] = ""
}

match($0, /.*<AUDIT_RECORD.* (TIMESTAMP="[^"]*").* CONNECTION_ID="([^"]*)".* (SQLTEXT="[^"]*").*/, a) {
    id = a[2]
    if (id in ids) {
        printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", "==========================================", a[1], a[3] > id ".txt"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...will you please suggest me a book to learn gawk scripting....I am completely new to it...

Comment: @vidyadhar I actually just learned Awk scripting by reading the manual of Gawk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html. And I just refer to `man gawk` everytime I code.

Comment: the above code given by you is fine and simple to understand....but it is taking more than 20 min to generate the files... Any help?

Comment: The script compared to others has a more careful approach so it's naturally slow. It stores data first on arrays, matches key patterns properly, prints data for a specific file at once, and makes sure that not more than one output file handle is open at a time. That's the best form it could have otherwise it would have same concept as other scripts shared on this thread.

Comment: @vidyadhar Ok I made a little simpler version of it which skips storing data but please consider the possibility of Awk having multiple opened files at a time.

Comment: The best answer to `will you please suggest me a book to learn gawk scripting` is: get the book `Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition` by Arnold Robbins. Yes, there's an online version of it, but sales of that book are the only recompense the guy who maintains gawk gets for all of his hard work.