# extract first entry from a file based on its corresponding ID list in second file?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk

I have a 2 text file. **file1** contains IDs:

```
0   ABCD  
3   ABDF
4   ACGFR
6   ABCD
7   GFHTRSFS
```

And **file2**:

```
ID001  AB  ACGFR  DF  FD  GF  TYFJ  ANH  
ID002  DFR  AG  ABDF  HGT  MNJ  POI  YUI
ID003  DGT  JHY  ABCD  YTRE  NHYT  PPOOI  IUYNB
ID004  GFHTRSFS  MJU  UHY  IUJ  POL  KUH  KOOL
```

If the second column of file 1 matches to any entry in file 2 then the first column of file 2 should be the answer for it.

The output should be like:

```
0   ID003
3   ID002
4   ID001
6   ID003
7   ID004
```

(2nd column of file1 (ABCD) found match to 3rd row of file 2 which has ID003. So, ID003 should be the answer to it).

I have tried examples form other posts too, but somehow they are not matching to this.

Any help will be grateful.

Kind Regards

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: @ Barmar and @ Matt. I am newbie to scripting. Although I have spend couple of hours on libre office-calc to solve this problem. But it didn't go my way. So at the end I had to post it here.

Comment: @Parthpatel Posting here is fine, but you need to follow the rules. And since you're asking a question about code, where's the code?

Comment: Check questions under `Related`, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471084/split-a-file-based-on-the-string-from-the-other-file?rq=1.  Then show your effort and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

When trying to match up records from one file with records in another, the idea is to use a `hash ( also known as an associative array, set of key-value pairs, or dictionaries )` to store the relationship between the first column and the rest of the columns.  In effect, create the following relationships:

```
file1: ABCD     -> 0
       ABDF     -> 3
       ACGFR    -> 4
       FGHTRSS  -> 6
       GFHTRSFS -> 7

file2: AB    -> ID001
       ACGFR -> ID001
       DF    -> ID001
       ...
       ANH   -> ID001
       DFR   -> ID002
       AG    -> ID002
       ...
       KUH   -> ID004
       KOOL  -> ID004
```

The actual matching up of records between the files amounts to determining
if both hashes, here file1 and file2 both have keys defined for each file1 record.  Here we can see that `ACGFR` is a key for both, therefore we can match up `4` and `ID001`, and so on for the rest of the keys.

In perl, we can create a hash by assigning pairs of values:

```
my %hash = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );
```

A hash can also be created using references:

```
my $hash_ref = { foo => 1, bar => 2 };
```

Keys can be found using the `keys` function, and individual values can be extracted:

```
my $val1 = $hash{ foo };       # regular hash
my $val2 = $hash_ref->{ foo }; # hash reference
```

Whether a particular key is a member of a hash can be tested using the `exists` function.

With that background out of the way, here is one way to do this in perl:

**matchup_files.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $usage = "usage: $0 file1 file2\n";

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
for my $file ($file1, $file2) {
    die $usage unless defined $file && -f $file; # -f checks whether $file is an actual file
}

# Create mappings col2 -> col1
#                 col3 -> col1
#                 col4 -> col1
my $h1 = inverted_hash_file_on_first_column( $file1 );
my $h2 = hash_file_on_first_column( $file2 );

# Try to find matching pairs
my $matches = {};
for my $h1_key ( keys %$h1 ) {
    my $h1_val = $h1->{$h1_key};
    if ( exists $h2->{ $h1_val } ) {
        # We have a match!
        my $num = $h1_key;
        my $id  = $h2->{ $h1_val };
        $matches->{ $num } = $id;
    }
}

# Print them out in numerical order
for my $num ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$matches ) {
    my $id = $matches->{$num};
    print join("  ", $num, $id) . "\n";
}

exit 0; # Success

sub inverted_hash_file_on_first_column {
    my ($file) = @_;
    return _hash_file($file, 1);
}

sub hash_file_on_first_column {
    my ($file) = @_;
    return _hash_file($file, 0);
}

sub _hash_file {
    my ($file, $inverted) = @_;

    my $fhash = {};
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Unable to open $file : $!";
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        my @fields = split /\s+/, $line; # Split line on whitespace
        my $key = shift @fields; # First column
        for my $field ( @fields ) {
            if ( $inverted ) {
                die "Duplicated field '$field'" if exists $fhash->{ $key };                
                $fhash->{ $key } = $field;
            } else {
                die "Duplicated field '$field'" if exists $fhash->{ $field };
                $fhash->{ $field } = $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return $fhash;
}
```

**output**

```
matchup_files.pl input1 input2
0  ID003
3  ID002
4  ID001
6  ID003
7  ID004
```

Comment: Hellow @xxfelixxx, Thank you for your help. However, If this perl script will work if i have multiple column to find from in second file? because file 2 has multiple column (any column can have a ID which I am looking for). Regards

Comment: It checks every column but the first for a possible match, so yes, it should work, try it out!

Comment: It should work but pardon me. when i run command. it ends up with error. "Duplicated field '12' at hi.perl line 46, <$fh> line 11"... Can u tell me what does this indicates?.. Kind Regards

Comment: I should have mentioned earlier that, My file can contain duplicate values in first column of file 1 (ID which I am searching in 2nd file).. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Of course, but you need to decide how to deal with that situation, should the first match win, should the lowest/highest id win, something else?  etc.

Comment: Can the same ID be assigned for every duplicate matches. because it will search every time from file 1. For your reference I have edited my question example. That might give u more idea. Because script will take a word from file 1 and search it against file 2. can we leave duplicate value as it is?

Comment: Its okay if first id win.. that will also work for me

Comment: Your welcome.  If the answer works, you should accept it.